# Best practice on loading images from servers

Tags: android, image-compression

Making an app that loads images from server.
 The image is just like an achievement badge that gets unlocked (i.e) loaded from the server.
 Am not sure on how to handle this scenario if there is no internet connection, as the image won't be available. Is that a good practice to store all the badge images in the assets. Will that make the app size big.
 Or is there any good way for compressing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ship them with your app. Badges only need small images, that can be compressed fairly efficient.

This reduces the overall complexcity and reliabilty of your application. Plus you save your servers and the enduser some overhead/traffic.